# cart total prices adding incorrect

Tags: javascript

im working on my e-commerce page, and i've noticed that my cart total is not working properly, and i have no idea why.

```
let cart = [];
let total = 0;
let modalCarrito = document.getElementById("cart")



const agregarAlCarrito = (indice) => {
    const indiceEncontradoCarrito = cart.findIndex((elemento) => {
        return elemento.id === productos[indice].id
    })
    if (indiceEncontradoCarrito === -1) {
        const productoAgregar = productos[indice]
        productoAgregar.cantidad = 1
        cart.push(productoAgregar)
        dibujarCarrito()
    }else {
        cart[indiceEncontradoCarrito].cantidad += 1
        dibujarCarrito()
    }

    Toastify({
        text: `Producto agregado al carrito.`,
        duration: 1500,
        style: {
            background: "linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(255,255,255,0.7231267507002801) 0%, rgba(79,79,79,1) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,1) 100%)",
          },
        }).showToast();
};




const dibujarCarrito = () => {
    modalCarrito.className = "cart";
    modalCarrito.innerHTML = ""     
    if(cart.length > 0) {
        cart.forEach((producto, indice) => {
            total = total + producto.precio * producto.cantidad;
            const carritoContainer = document.createElement("div");
            carritoContainer.className = "producto-carrito"
            carritoContainer.innerHTML = `
            <img class = "car-img" src="${producto.imagen}"/>
            <div class="product-details">
                ${producto.nombre}
            </div>
            <div class="product-details"> Cantidad: ${producto.cantidad}</div>
            <div class="product-details"> Precio: $ ${producto.precio}</div>
            <div class="product-details"> Subtotal: $ ${
                producto.precio * producto.cantidad
            }</div>
            <button class="btn btn-dark" id="remove-product" onClick="removeProduct(${indice})">Eliminar producto</button>
            `;
            modalCarrito.appendChild(carritoContainer);
        })
        
        const totalContainer = document.createElement("div")
        totalContainer.className = "total-carrito";
        totalContainer.innerHTML = `<div class = "total"> TOTAL $ ${total} </div>
        <button class = "btn btn-dark finalizar" id="finalizar" onClick = "finalizarCompra()"> FINALIZAR COMPRA </button>`
        modalCarrito.appendChild(totalContainer)

        localStorage.setItem("productos", JSON.stringify(cart)) 
    } else {
        modalCarrito.classList.remove("cart")
    }         
}

 

const removeProduct = (indice) => {
    cart.splice(indice, 1);
    dibujarCarrito();

}
```

I was trying to solve it 2 days in a row and I can't find the reason why it is adding more, I would really appreciate your help, since it is my page for my final project for my fullstack course

Comment: In `dibujarCarrito()` reset `total` to `0` in the beginning. Otherwise it will keep counting up.

Comment: _not working properly_ is not a sufficiently detailed description of the problem you are having.  What is the behaviour you expect?  What actually happens instead?

Comment: hi wyck, its adding extra price

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a couple suggestions. First, did you debug your code to make sure your cart list items didn't contain any duplicates? Make sure you are only iterating over the items that are supposed to be in the cart.

Now, if I am reading your code right... if you are trying to iterate over a bunch of items to determine a "total price" of all items in the cart, maybe you can use reduce for that? So in your dibujarCarrito method, first do something like this

```
let initialTotal = 0;
const grandTotal = cart.reduce((previousValue, currentItem) => previousValue + (currentItem.precio * currentItem.cantidad),
initialTotal);
```

I think that should get you the total cost of all the items in the cart. Then you can carry on with your view logic of building out HTML elements and whatnot.